# How do you groupby with pandas that sums values in the same column but is offset by a set number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table that looks like the table below. I want to group by id, start_time, and approach so I can add the right, thru, left, and u-turn for each similar timestamp.

| intersection_id | start_time | approach | movement | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 2 |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 4 |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 6 |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | 4 |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | 6 |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | 8 |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Left | 6 |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Left | 8 |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Left | 10 |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | 10 |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | 12 |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | 14 |

Example results:

| intersection_id | start_time | approach | movement | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 24 |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 30 |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 38 |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | nan |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | nan |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | nan |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Left | nan |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | Left | nan |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | Left | nan |
| 799028 | 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | nan |
| 799028 | 12:15:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | nan |
| 799028 | 12:30:00 AM | Southbound | U-turn | nan |

This will repeat itself until it goes through all the IDs and approaches.

I have tried a few different ways:

```
df['app_sum'] = df.groupby(['intersection_id','start_time','approach'], as_index=False)['volume'].transform('sum')
```

However, this code will not group correctly and will not provide nan values; it will repeat the values once it gets through the initial set of timestamps.

The second code I tried was

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=4, offset=-3)
df['app_sum'] = (
    df.groupby(['intersection_id','start_time','approach'])['volume'].rolling(window=indexer).sum().droplevel(0))
```

I know this is wrong because there is no window.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
df['volume'] = (df.groupby(['intersection_id', 'start_time', 'approach'])
                  ['volume'].transform('sum')
                  .where(df['movement'].eq('Right'))
                )
```

output:

```
    intersection_id    start_time     approach movement  volume
0            799028  12:00:00 AM   Southbound    Right     22.0
1            799028  12:15:00 AM   Southbound    Right     30.0
2            799028  12:30:00 AM   Southbound    Right     38.0
3            799028  12:00:00 AM   Southbound     Thru      NaN
4            799028  12:15:00 AM   Southbound     Thru      NaN
5            799028  12:30:00 AM   Southbound     Thru      NaN
6            799028  12:00:00 AM   Southbound     Left      NaN
7            799028  12:15:00 AM   Southbound     Left      NaN
8            799028  12:30:00 AM   Southbound     Left      NaN
9            799028  12:00:00 AM   Southbound   U-turn      NaN
10           799028  12:15:00 AM   Southbound   U-turn      NaN
11           799028  12:30:00 AM   Southbound   U-turn      NaN
```